# The "FindConfigFiles" task failed unexpectedly. Visual studio and Typescript issue with VS2015 Angular 2

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular

This is the issue, cannot even understand why this issue is occuring.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       The "FindConfigFiles" task failed unexpectedly.
System.InvalidOperationException: The item metadata "%(FullPath)" cannot be applied to the path "content\scripts\angular\typings\node_modules\typings-core\node_modules\popsicle\node_modules\form-data\node_modules\combined-stream\node_modules\delayed-stream\test\integration\test-delayed-stream.js". content\scripts\angular\typings\node_modules\typings-core\node_modules\popsicle\node_modules\form-data\node_modules\combined-stream\node_modules\delayed-stream\test\integration\test-delayed-stream.js
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidOperation(String resourceName, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ErrorUtilities.VerifyThrowInvalidOperation(Boolean condition, String resourceName, Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2)
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.FileUtilities.ItemSpecModifiers.GetItemSpecModifier(String currentDirectory, String itemSpec, String definingProjectEscaped, String modifier, String& fullPath)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.BuiltInMetadata.GetMetadataValueEscaped(String currentDirectory, String evaluatedIncludeBeforeWildcardExpansionEscaped, String evaluatedIncludeEscaped, String definingProjectEscaped, String name, String& fullPath)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectItemInstance.TaskItem.GetBuiltInMetadataEscaped(String name)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectItemInstance.TaskItem.GetMetadataEscaped(String metadataName)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectItemInstance.TaskItem.GetMetadata(String metadataName)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FindConfigFiles.<>c.b__12_0(ITaskItem f)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereArrayIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at TypeScript.Tasks.FindConfigFiles.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your project structure, "node_modules" folders, "obj" folders, etc..,
please exclude from your project structure.

How to exclude from project structure,..

-In Solution Explorer, Right click on these folder and > Click Exclude From Project.

-And build and clean your project solution,.

Good Luck!!

Comment: Thanks , actually I excluded node_modules but I also haves same all js files which are in node_modules copied in other Scripts Folder .. which I removed and was working fine.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same build error today when I moved to VS2017 and tried to build a project. And every search returned this S.O. post so I figured I should post what worked for me since the accepted answer didn't work for me. (Excluding node_modules from the project made VS crash)

In the csproj file I removed these lines

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props')" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />
```

And the project was able to build correctly.

I found this answer from [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15536) on TypeScript's github page. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This didn't fix my issue, but it did get me farther than anything else

Answer (score 3):

Had similar issues during migration from VS 2015 to 2017.

```
Error       The "FindConfigFiles" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.
Error       The "IsFileSystemCaseSensitive" parameter is not supported by the "FindConfigFiles" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.
```

Fixed by 
- closing VS 2017, 
- uninstalling old VS TypeScript plugin, 
- removing nuget plugin packages (also cleaning physical folder just in case),
- installing TypeScript SDK for Visual Studio 2017.

Maybe it would save someone's time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting here because I wish I had found this earlier. I faced a similar problem when publishing my ASP.NET Core MVC solution in VS2015. It turned out that inside [Solution name]\bin\Release\PublishOutput there was a rogue bin folder with the following contents:

> ```
> [Rogue bin folder]\bin\Release\PublishOutput\bin\Release\PublishOutput...
> ```

I don't know for how long it went but I deleted it and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do two things to get this fixed for me with AzureDev Ops, a search that brought me to this.

First, remove lines that look like this (as mentioned by @Ju66ernaut):

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />
```

There were a few of those lines, what you are looking for is the $(MSBuildExtensionsPath32) variable and TypeScript.

Second, change this from 2.2 to 3.9 (latest version as of this comment.

```
TypeScriptToolsVersion>3.9</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```